# no more data to read from socket" For just Production and suddenly happen

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I got error in our application suddenly happen
our Application it was work fine after time I got this error without any change
and we use same code  in Dev env  connect with Dev db not prod db (also no like this error)
the error happen just in production
in our application we use(Spring ,Hibernate, and Oracle Db).does anyone have idea why we got like this error after it was working fine:

```
Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
2022-01-07 14:27:32,465 WARN]: Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call DBMS_DBFS_CONTENT.CREATEDIRECTORY(?, ?, ?, CASE  WHEN ? = 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)}]; No more data to read from socket; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:98)
```

Comment: This error can sometimes happens when the server process crashes so bad that it doesn't even have the ability to raise a proper error message. But the server does usually log a message on the file system. You should ask your DBA to check the alert log for recent ORA-600 or ORA-7445 errors. Those trace files will often have more information. You're probably running into a bug, which can be very specific to edition, version, operating system, etc., which may explain why it only happens on production.

Comment: Can you format your question a bit for readability?